# How to print(something) by using multiproceesing.pool and queue

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, pool

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import multiprocessing
import queue
import time

def myTask(queue):
  value = queue.get()
  print("Process {} Popped {} from the shared Queue".format(multiprocessing.current_process().pid, value))
  queue.task_done()

def main():
  m = multiprocessing.Manager()
  sharedQueue = m.Queue()
  sharedQueue.put(2)
  sharedQueue.put(3)
  sharedQueue.put(4)

  process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=myTask, args=(sharedQueue,))
  process1.start()
  process1.join()

  process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=myTask, args=(sharedQueue,))
  process2.start()
  process2.join()

  process3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=myTask, args=(sharedQueue,))
  process3.start()
  process3.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
  print("Done")
```

I want to print following sentence.

print("Process {} Popped {} from the shared Queue".format(multiprocessing.current_process().pid, value))

but there's some problem in here

How can I do that?

Comment: what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think `Pool` is not designed for what you want to do. It should be used to run in parallel a specific function with defined arguments, therefor the read of the queue must happen before you ask the pool to run:

```
import multiprocessing # I just call & use multiprocessing (queue is included)

def my_function(value):
    """ the function to run """
    print("Process {} Popped {} from the shared Queue".format(multiprocessing.current_process().pid, value), flush=True)

def main():
    # Create the queue
    shared_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    # Fill the queue
    shared_queue.put_nowait(2)
    shared_queue.put_nowait(3)
    shared_queue.put_nowait(4)

    # Create the pool
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(3)
    # Pass the content of the queue as list to the pool
    p.map(my_function, [shared_queue.get() for i in range(shared_queue.qsize())])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print("Done")
```

Comment: >>> 
========================= RESTART: C:/Python35/q1.py =========================
Done

Comment: and I want to use Process() method, so be similar to my previous code.

Comment: @LeeChanghwa, my output is: 
Process 14252 Popped 2 from the shared Queue
Process 14252 Popped 3 from the shared Queue
Process 14252 Popped 4 from the shared Queue
Done
For both the codes...
Can you please tell me if you run it on windows or linux? What tooling you are using to run it?

Comment: To verify something, can you change your print as `print("Process {} Popped {} from the shared Queue".format(multiprocessing.current_process().pid, value), flush=True)` ?